# Who is interested in a TeX.SX group on LinkedIn?

Tags: discussion, logo, social-networking

As the community on TeX.SX is growing, who would be interested in identifying themselves with it on LinkedIn by creating a group there? (There already is a Stack Overflow group for example.)

**Edit:** Rephrased the question, in the hope to get answers :-)

**Edit 2:** If I create the group, can I use the TeX.SX logo for it?

Comment: LinkedIn? I am not a member.

Comment: Logo: I'd get permission first, cf. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22117/what-are-the-rules-on-using-the-stack-overflow-logo and http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance

Answer (score 3):

Maybe.  The Latex group that exists there already is kind of lame.  I don't suppose having a Tex.sx group hurts, though.

It would be most use if we could ensure that we can find user profiles here from the list of members of the group there.

Comment: I think it is possible to restrict the group somehow, maybe by asking for the TeX.SX id upon joining.